# Do Special Relativity and Newton's Law of Unverisal Gravitation hold in flat space?

Tags: special-relativity, newtonian-gravity

These principles both seem to apply in flat space. Perhaps they are related through the equation for work (Fs=W)?

Comment: There is more than one "flat space". Newton's law applies in the classical Euclidean 3D space. Special relativity applies in [4D Minkowski space (spacetime)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Four-dimensional_Euclidean_spacetime).

Comment: Special relativity is valid in a flat Minkowski spacetime. The Newtonian law of gravity is based on the Galilean spacetime, in which the speed of light is infinite. In addition, this law is an asymptotic approximation of General relativity for a week gravitation. So Newtonian gravity works only for slow moving objects in a weak gravity. For these reasons special relativity would be compatible with Newtonian gravity only at slow speeds where special relativity can be replaced by the Newtonian mechanics based on the Galilean spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

No. Newton's law of universal gravitation does not have a signal propagation delay built into it, the way Maxwell's laws of electromagnetism do. It is therefore able to transmit information faster than light, which special relativity cannot bear (such information appears in various reference frames to travel backwards in time). You would have to at the minimum modify it to contain those propagation delays. The most obvious way would be to simply copy Maxwell's laws as they electric field has a $1/r^2$ force law, too -- this is called [gravitoelectromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism) -- but that Wikipedia page says that the corresponding theory does not have true Lorentz invariance as would be hoped.

Comment: Maybe that was too much to ask. Do SR and Newtonian gravity both apply in flat space, but just in separate instances of physics?

Comment: Also, in a special case where the reference frame is moving just as close to light-speed as the physics of two objects (3 radio-waves moving through a vacuum), Newton's law cannot transmit information faster than light, no?

Comment: (1) No. SR applies in flat spacetime; Newtonian gravity applies in flat space with a universal time coordinate. The difference is that one of these obeys the Galileian coordinate transformation $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-\beta&1\end{bmatrix}$ and one uses the Lorentz transformation $\frac1{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&-\beta\\-\beta&1\end{bmatrix}.$ It's a subtle difference but it's there. (2) Newton's law can always transmit information faster than light.  The reference frame does not matter.